# Looping in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to run regression over each id. I aslo need to narrow it down to regression by each year within a particular id.

```
tsset id date

forvalues i=1/3 {

eststo:quietly arch rtr mon tue wed thu fri lag1r lag2r if id == `i' & Year==`i', noconstant arch(1/1) tarch(1/1) garch(1/1) distribution(t)
}


esttab using d:\Return_reg.csv, append cells("b(fmt(8))")
```

It returns the following error:

> no observations.

I suspect it's because years are different within each id.

How do I need to improve code so I achieve my goal?

Comment: Also asked, with somewhat different wording, at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1319144-regress-by-a-period

Comment: In essence you are testing whether `Year` is 1, 2, 3 just as you are testing whether `id` is. Typo bug.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a typo (unless your year variable really only takes the values 1, 2 and 3). Furthermore, tsset takes only one argument; if you want to declare panel data, you need to use xtset. Try the following:

```
xtset id date
levelsof Year, local(years) //create list containing all values of year
levelsof id, local(ids)     //create list containing all values of id
foreach id in `ids'{
    foreach yr in `years'{
        eststo: quietly arch rtr mon tue wed thu fri lag1r lag2r if id == `id' & Year==`yr', noconstant arch(1/1) tarch(1/1) garch(1/1) distribution(t)
    }
}
```